# How to avoid repeated pre-calculation in django view

Tags: python, django

I am writing an API which returns json according to queries. For example: `localhost/api/query?a=1&b=2`. To return the json, I need to do some pre-calculations to calculate a value, say, `x`. The pre-calculation takes long time *(several hundred milliseconds)*. For example, The json file returns the value of `x+a+b.`
When the user query `localhost/api/query?a=3&b=4`, `x` will be calculate again and this is a waste of time since `x` won't change for any query. The question is how can I do this pre-calculation of `x` for all queries *(In the real app, `x` is not a value but a complex object returned by wrapped C++ code)*.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using some sort of cache (memcached, redis) you can store it there. You can try to serialize the object with pickle, msgpack etc. That you can retrieve and deserialze it.

Comment: I tried pickle. For simple python objects it's OK to serialize it and then fetch it by deserialization. However, the object is a C++ class wrapped by boost_python. It read that Pickling of "libNetwork.Network" instances is not enabled (http://www.boost.org/libs/python/doc/v2/pickle.html)

Comment: I do not know what server you are using, but it seems that this object  should be created once per process/thread/whatever (put it in separate module where you initialize it) and shared between calls, but keep in mind that the object should be thread safe. If the server is process based (has several workers - like gunicorn, every process and possibly every thread should have it's own object). Without the details about the object and how it works there is little we can help you with (sorry)...

Answer (score 1):

You could add a model (with a db table) that stores values for a, b and x.  Then for each query, you could look for an instance with a and b and return the associated x.

Comment: Thank you. But it seems difficult to store the wrapped object to a data table, at least I don't know how...

Comment: If it's a json object, you can do a dumps (dump as a string) to a TextField in your models/db.